# Are iPhone apps based on a grid?

Tags: grids, mobile, ios, iphone, design-specifications

Google provides all design specifications in their design documentation, which is very rich and outlines every single element - its size, padding etc. Everything, including material icons and text fields, is based on an 8px grid so you're pretty much never left in the dark.

What about iPhone apps? Apple human interface guidelines are very vague and, in some ways, completely useless. That's why I'm reaching out to you guys. how do you position and size your design assets such as icons, bars, tabs etc.? I would like to be as precise as possible since that's just the way I design stuff. How are designs being put together in xcode? Is there anything I need to consider?

Comment: Not sure if "paint by numbers" is design though. :)

Comment: @Scott It is design, just *programmatic* design

Comment: Eh.. I disagree @ZachSaucier Someone laying out every single thing for you is **not** design.. it's purely implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apple is a little less " holding your hand" guide: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

there are however sizes for the icon and screen dimensions to be considered:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

in x code all designs are assembled in the xib area/ main storyboard
unless of course you are coding out the assets/colors

but to answer your question: no it is not grid based framework, it is up to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

> Are iPhone apps based on a grid?

No. Not any one in particular.

And keep in mind that Material Design isn't a system dictated for all Android apps. Just Android apps that want to use Google's Material Design specification.

> How are designs being put together in xcode?

That's a pretty broad topic and not really answerable here. But you can create a UI for an iPhone app in a number of ways--none of which that I know of restrict you to any particular 'grid'.